# AWS CLI: The config profile (example) could not be found

Tags: linux, macos, amazon-web-services, installation, aws-cli

I'm trying to setup an new named profile using the awscli

I used `aws configure --profile example` to set the profile up but I left everything as the default

Now I'm getting `The config profile (example) could not be found`

I even tried creating and modifying the `~\.aws\config` file with the following but to no avail

```
[example]
region=eu-west-1
output=text
```

Any command I try to execute will result in the above error

I also tried reinstalling the awscli

Help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Check user and  permissions for config and credentials files: `ls -la .aws`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

FWIR if you leave the defaults then it won't create the profile since the defaults are all `NONE`.

Your format is not quite correct for creating the profile configuration manually.

It should be

```
[profile example]
region=eu-west-1
output=text
```